# captcha calculation not working

Tags: php, html, captcha

I'm kinda new into PHP and I am working on a captcha that generates a sum. 
e.g. 17 + 4

It does the calculation good, but I want that what the person types in the input field matches the answer that PHP calculates and then echo. If it's wrong, then echo another sentence. Please help me!

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .wrapper {
                width: 100%;
                text-align: center;
                margin-top: 100px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <?PHP
                $first_calculation = rand(5, 20);
                $second_calculation = rand(2, 10);
                $answer = $first_calculation + $second_calculation;
                $captcha = $_POST['captcha'];
                if (isset($captcha)) {
                    if ($captcha == $answer) {
                        echo '<font color="green">Correct!</font>';
                    }
                    else {
                        echo '<font color="red">The answer you filled in was wrong. Please try again.</font>';
                    }
                }
            ?>
            <form action="index.php" method="post">
                <h3>Prove that you're human!</h3>
                <?PHP
                    echo $first_calculation
                ?> +
                <?PHP
                    echo $second_calculation
                ?>
                <input type="text" name="captcha" value="">
                <input type="submit" value="submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: PHP is processed on the server. What you're doing is generating random numbers and displaying them. Then when the page is submitted, new random number are generated and being compared to what the user answered with the first set of random numbers. This'll sure be secure...no one will ever get past it.

Comment: Ohh.. didn't even think about that. Well how am I able to fix this?

Comment: even if this worked, its still security through obscurity, you're counting in the fact that bots haven't been taught to do basic math

Comment: You'll need to [start a session](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) and save the generated value in the session. Then, when the data is posted, you can compare it to the value that was previously stored. If it matches, you're done. Otherwise, generate a new captcha.

Comment: @andrew Security through obscurity. Isn't that exactly what captcha is about? With other captchas you're just assuming that bots can't read pictures. Besides, a custom implementation is less likely to be recognised by bots. Even a field in a form with a label *'type the letter 'a' here'* can be enough to stop spambots, as long as you apply it on a small enough scale.

Comment: option 1 :`<input type="hidden" value="answer" value="<?php echo $answer; ?>">`

Answer (score 0):

A bit safer practice...

Create a file called captcha.php
and put the following code there:

```
<?php
function str_write_captcha($mime_type,$s_path,$string)
{
    if((strcmp("jpeg",$mime_type)==0) ||( strcmp("jpg",$mime_type)==0))
    {
        header("Content Type:image/jpeg");  // Set the mime type as jpeg
        $im     = imagecreatefromjpeg($s_path);  //load the image
        $orange = imagecolorallocate($im, 45, 45, 45);  // pass the color of the font to be written
        $px     = (imagesx($im) - 9 * strlen($string)) / 2;  //set the  X position of the string
        $py     = imagesy($im) - 36 ;             //set the  Y position of the string
        imagestring($im, 6, $px, $py, $string, $orange); //Write the string on the image
        imagejpeg($im);  //Generate the jpeg image
        return (imagejpeg($im));
    }
    else if(strcmp("png",$mime_type)==0)
    {
        header("Content Type:image/png");  // Set the mime type as jpeg
        $im     = imagecreatefrompng($s_path); //load the image
        $orange = imagecolorallocate($im, 45, 45, 45); // pass the color of the font to be written
        $px     = (imagesx($im) - 9 * strlen($string)) / 2; //set the  X position of the string
        $py     = imagesy($im) - 36 ;  //set the  Y position of the string
        imagestring($im, 5, $px, $py, $string, $orange);  //Write the string on the image
        imagepng($im);  //Generate the png image
        return (imagepng($im));
    }
    else
    {
        print("<B>UNKNOWN MIME TYPE !!! </B>");
    }
}

if(!$_SESSION['capt'] {
    $first_calculation = rand(5, 20);
    $second_calculation = rand(2, 10);
    $string = $first_calculation + $second_calculation;
    $_SESSION['capt'] = $answer;
}
echo str_write_captcha('png','/images/my_background_image.png',$string)
?>
```

In your page where you'd like to include the captcha just use:

```
<img src="captcha.php">
```

And keeping with your logic:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .wrapper {
                width: 100%;
                text-align: center;
                margin-top: 100px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <?PHP
                $captcha = $_POST['captcha'];
                if (isset($captcha)) {
                    if ($captcha == $_SESSION['capt']) {
                        echo '<font color="green">Correct!</font>';
                        // UNSET the session 
                        // $_SESSION['capt'] = '';
                    }
                    else {
                        echo '<font color="red">The answer you filled in was wrong. Please try again.</font>';
                    }
                }
            ?>
            <form action="index.php" method="post">
                <h3>Prove that you're human!</h3>
                <img src="captcha.php">
                <input type="text" name="captcha" value="">
                <input type="submit" value="submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```